# how to get your last known location saved in iOS devices?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

in Android there's a method called `getLastLocation()` which allow you to get the last location saved in case if the GPS is disabled for example, is there possibly any function works like that in Swift ?

and is it possibly to compare the accuracy between the results of internet GPS and real GPS ?

Answer (score 6):

The `CLLocationManager` class has the `location` property, which contains:

> The most recently retrieved user location.

The [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location) further states that:

> The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.

---

I can't give you concrete data re: accuracy of different location services hardware; but I strongly suggest a look through the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ***NSUserDefault*** save the location from location manager on did update location method to some key in **NSUserDefault**,and then access that later on your need. As per my knowledge there is no such function like android!